# Error on BULK insert date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to BULK insert into sql server 2008 and i get an error on the Date column.

```
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy

BULK
INSERT CustomSelection
FROM 'c:\test.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Date).

This is the Date in the .csv file: 18/08/2012. 
Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date format is invalid thats way sql server giving error .

To solve these type of issue you have to follow following steps : 
1. Import csv in database table , table column must be varchar it should not be datetime . 
2. Then run following query to find invalid dates .

```
select inserteddate from table where isdate(inserteddate) = 0
```

3. then update those date manually or by update query something like :

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET INSERTEDDATE = CONVERT(DATETIME , '18/08/2012' , 105)
WHERE INSERTEDDATE = '18/08/2012'
```